# Confusion About Ember Resource vs Routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have been reading `Ember CLI 101` to understand the resource / route distinction but am having trouble understanding the situation below:

I created a new project with ember-cli and ran:

`ember g resource testme --pod`

and

`ember g route testme/testresource --pod`.

Then, I added changed `testme/template.hbs` to look like:

```
This is test me1.
{{outlet}}
```

and changed `testme/testresource/template.hbs` to look like

```
This is the test resource .

{{outlet}}
```

The routes look something like

```
  this.resource('testme', function() {
    this.resource('testresource', function() {});
  });
```

Why is it the case that navigating to

http://localhost:4200/testme/testresource

presents just

```
This is test me1.
```

and not

```
This is test me1. This is the test resource .
```

If I change `testresource` to a `route`, I get the both sentences. Why don't I get both if `testresource` is a `resource`? What's the point of having the 2nd template if it doesn't get rendered?

For reference, my dependencies look like:

```
"jquery": "^1.11.1",
"ember": "1.10.0",
"ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.15",
```

Comment: Use routes, [resources are going away](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/router-this-resource-gone-from-documentation-v1-11-0/7833) and you can now (as of 1.7.0 IIRC) nest routes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resources have their own namespace, routes under resources are namespaced beneath the resource above them.

When Ember is resolving the `testresource` template it follows this pattern.  If it's a `resource` in the router it will look for a template named `testresource`.  If it's a `route` in the router it will look for `resource/route` ie `testme/testresource`.